# What's the difference between a Perl sub declaration with and without parentheses?

Tags: perl

What is exactly the difference (if there is any) between:

```
sub foobar() {
    # doing some stuff
}
```

and

```
sub foobar {
    # doing some stuff
}
```

I see some of each, and the first syntax sometimes fail to compile.

Comment: The first is a prototype that says the function takes no arguments; the second is not a prototype and doesn't say anything about arguments.  Use the second form.  See [Far more than you ever wanted to know about prototypes in Perl](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=861966).

Comment: In `5.20` *experimental* function signatures also use parens, http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2015/04/use-v5-20-subroutine-signatures/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By putting the `()` on the end of the subroutine name, you are giving it a prototype. A prototype gives Perl hints about the number and types of the arguments that you will be passing to the subroutine. See [this section in perlsub](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Prototypes) for details.

Specifically, `()` is the empty prototype which tells Perl that this subroutine takes no arguments and Perl will throw a compilation error if you then call this subroutine with arguments. Here's an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

sub foo {
  say 'In foo';
}

sub bar() {
  say 'In bar';
}

foo();
bar();
foo(1);
bar(1);
```

The output from this is:

```
Too many arguments for main::bar at ./foobar line 18, near "1)"
Execution of ./foobar aborted due to compilation errors.
```

It's that last call to `bar()` (the one with the argument of 1) which causes this error.

It's worth noting that Perl's implementation of prototypes is generally not as useful as people often think that they are and that outside of a few specialised cases, most Perl experts will avoid them. I recommend that you do the same.  As of Perl v5.22, the experimental "signatures" feature is in testing that will hopefully accomplish many of the goals programmers from other languages would have expected from prototypes.

Comment: "hints about the number and types of the arguments" is a valuable information if you read someones script. Is it not worth to put these hints inside the code? Can you tell why is that most people avoid it?

Comment: Tom Christiansen [wrote it](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=861966) far better than I could.

Comment: @Matthias If T.C.'s P.M. post is TL;DR, you could consider the ambiguities involved with perl's array and hash types; `foo($a, $b)` might as well be `foo(@args)`, etc.   The world splits into two camps after that, people who are going to run away in horror and stay as far from the language as they can, and people who see it as a stroke of genius or luck.   Keep in mind it is also a language with a well established documentation style (POD), and this might be considered *an appropriate separation of responsibilities* for a **dynamically typed** language.